# IOS Enable Indicate vs Notify

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth-lowenergy

According to the documentation from apple, we can use setNotifyValue(true, for: /characteristic/) to enable both Indicate and Notify.

However, I ONLY want to enable Indicate.... does Swift 4 provide a way to do this yet? It's possible on Android with the following:

```
bluetoothDescriptor.setValue(BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_INDICATION_VALUE);
bluetoothGatt.writeDescriptor(bluetoothDescriptor);
```

Where BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_INDICATION_VALUE = {0x02, 0x00}

Does this sound familiar to anyone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This functionality is provided by Core Bluetooth, not Swift, so the Swift version is irrelevant; The functionality is the same in Swift, Objective-C or even C#.

From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/cbperipheral/1518949-setnotifyvalue):

> If the specified characteristic is configured to allow both notifications and indications, calling this method enables notifications only.

The only way to receive indications and not notifications is for the peripheral to provide only indications for the relevant characteristic, and for it to declare this via the characteristic descriptor.